# Discord Bot - Wait for Reply after Interaction

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Probably I didn't understand quite well how Discord API works when we use `awaitMessages`. What I'm trying to do is to wait for a message from the user after a button was clicked in a private channel:

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {

if (interaction.isButton()) {
    if (interaction.customId.startsWith('dialogue-')) {
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#1a8175')
            .setTitle(' Dialogue')
            .setDescription('Please type your dialgoue')

        await interaction.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})

        // My problem lies here
        const filter = m => m.author.id === interaction.author.id;
        await interaction.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
            max: 1,
            time: 60000,
            errors: ['time']
        }).then(
            async(collected) => {
                await interaction.channel.send('Received: ' + collected.first().content.toLowerCase())
            })
    }
}
```

As you can see, the user clicks on the button, a message is sent asking for the dialogue. After that the bot should receive the next message.

After debugging I saw that everything that I type after the message is sent to the user, triggers the `messageCreate` event, which is why my code is not working. In my understanding, when we use `awaitMessages` the bot should wait for the Promise to be completed. I can't figure out what I am missing here. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading more the documentation, I found another way to do the same task: Using [MessageCollectors](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors)

```
const filter = m => m.author.id === interaction.user.id
        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {max: 1, time: 60000})
        collector.once('collect', async (message) => {
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#1a8175')
                .setTitle(` Dialogue ${dialogueNumber} received with success!!`)
                .setDescription(`Dialogue received: ${message.content}`)

            await interaction.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
        })
```

It does the job and works well. However the `time` directive is not working properly. I have set the time to 4s in order to send a message back to the user if it takes too long to reply. Using the listener `end` should do the job, somehow is not working and the bot is waiting for the reply for a long time (I prefer that way) but I would like to understand why the bot is still hanging there, waiting for the user to reply. I have a feeling that the filter must be wrong:

```
        collector.on('end', collected => {
            if (collected.size === 0) {
                interaction.channel.send('Timeout - You did not send a dialogue')
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the user who initialised the interaction, you should use `Interaction#user`. Whilst you should use `Message#author` to access the author of a message, you would need to use `user` for interactions.

```js
const filter = m => m.author.id === interaction.user.id;
```

You can always refer to [the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) if you don't know about certain properties or methods.

Answer (score 0):

As [@GodderE2D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16355189/goddere2d) said you need to change `interaction.author.id` to [`interaction.user.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=user) in your filter.

You also need to move your filter in the object according to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CollectorOptions) like this:

```js
const filter = m => m.author.id === interaction.user.id
interaction.channel.awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, time: 60000 })
```